# Rails 4: gem 'impressionist' to count view on pins/show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model-view-controller, counter

I have rails have where users can create pins. And I would like to render a number of views on the pin show page. Lets say that pins are profiles, I want to render the number of times a profile has been viewed.

So I installed the [impressionist gem](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist)

And here is how I implemented it:

**App/models/pin.rb**

```
  is_impressionable
```

**App/controllers/pin_controller.rb**

```
  impressionist actions: [:show]
```

**App/views/pins/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @pin.impressionist_count %>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't render the number of views, it shows 0 instead. It is worth noticing that I don't care to get unique IP adress views, I want the number of views being updated every time a user click on the show action of a pin.

Any ideas to put me on track ?

UPDATE 1:

As I am using friendly ID on my pins model I removed the following line from my pin_controller:

```
  impressionist actions: [:show]
```

And I updated the show view of the controller:

```
 def show
    @disable_nav = true
    @pin.upvoted_users
    impressionist(@pin)
    @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @pin
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

But now here is the error I have:

undefined method `impressions_count' for #

SOLUTION:

My bad... I forget to run the impressions_count to my model:

```
Rails generate migration add_impressions_count_to_pins impressions_count:integer 
Rake db:migrate
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: did you done `rails g impressionist` and `rake db:migrate`

Comment: Yeah of course, the thing is that I am using friendly_id gem, I'll update my question. see -> UPDATE 1.

Answer (score 0):

In View

```
<%= @pin.impressionist_count %>
```

change above one to the below one

```
<%= @pin.impression_count %>
```

or you can do

```
<%= @pin.impressionist_count(:filter=>:ip_address) %>
```

As per [README](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/cacdd66fd83a9b6ca391139cf989dc08ca86da51/README.md)

Comment: Nop it's not working, I have this error: undefined method `impressions_count' for #<Pin:0x007fc5fa79b658>